# bar plot in r with categorical variable on x axis

Tags: r

I have the data below and I'd just like to plot it as a simple barplot, where the height of bars is the "avgLSAmount" and the x axis is labeled with the corresponding zipcode.  If anyone can let me know how to do that I'd appreciate it.

data:

```
structure(list(zipcode = c(80123L, 80207L, 80205L, 80209L, 80206L, 
80204L, 80203L), avgLSAmount = c(643672.111111111, 815317.647058823, 
1095204.0625, 1604603.80733945, 1963074.61111111, 3282143.1372549, 
3618437.5)), .Names = c("zipcode", "avgLSAmount"), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with `base` plotting functionality you could use the following code:

```
barplot(height = data$avgLSAmount, names.arg = data$zipcode)
```

with the `lattice` package, it could look like this

```
library(lattice)
barchart(avgLSAmount ~ as.factor(zipcode) , data = data, horizontal = FALSE, xlab = "zipcode")
```

with `ggplot2`, the code could look like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = data, mapping = aes(x = as.factor(zipcode), y = avgLSAmount)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  labs(x = "zipcode")
```